# How to exit file reading mode (in `less`) in Linux terminal?

Tags: terminal, cygwin, less

I have just installed Cygwin, and I have displayed a file's contents using the `less` command. Now I am unable to exit that in order to type other commands:

[image]

I want to exit this mode to type some other commands. How can I do that?

Comment: I also use cygwin `cat` but it does not require to press anything when it has finished to print file. Add `cat --version` just in case to your question and perhaps a copy of your screen.

Comment: Sorry its less command I have updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 103, accepted):

To quit `less`, type <kbd>q</kbd>.

Also, check out `man less`, or type <kbd>h</kbd> from within `less` for some more, useful bits of information.

In general, assuming `man` has been properly installed, `man xyz` will tell you how to use the `xyz` tool. On GNU systems like Cygwin or what you call *Linux* at least, `man` will usually display through `less` as well, so to exit from `man`, again you would type <kbd>q</kbd> (which also works in `more` or `most` which are other pagers used by `man` or other commands that need paging on other systems).

Comment: Typing `q` does not work if I am using less under tmux, is it normal case? Please see: https://superuser.com/questions/1646175/pressing-q-does-not-exit-in-less-running-in-tmux

Comment: Ironically, at least in my Terminal (iTerm2), running `man xyz` will actually run `less` and leave you in the same predicament – I found this question precisely because I’d run a `man` command and couldn’t get back to the regular prompt.

Comment: This is not intuitive IMO... every other command can be exited with ctrl-C

Answer (score 2):

I think you can exit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Ctrl+C does not exit from less on my system, at least.

Comment: The user said `cat` in his original question that we answered.

Comment: less can be run with flag `-K` or `--quit-on-intr` and then it will terminate on Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Q</kbd> (lowercase). No need to press anything else. Some times, you need a capital letter.